# Android: Determine category of installed apps

Tags: android

Given the list of installed packages on an Android device, is there a way to sort the applications into categories without using a self-compiled hard-coded list of apps in categories?

For example, if the installed apps were Phone, Angry Birds & Messages, Phone & Messages might be in Communications and Angry Birds in Games.

I've seen [How to get Category for each App on device on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710442/how-to-get-category-for-each-app-on-device-on-android) yet hoped there may be a method that has come along since.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because apps don't have categories.  Apps don't need to be installed through google play, the categories on other stores won't be the same.  It may never have been installed from a store to begin with-  I sideload apps all the time written by myself or friends.  Th concept doesn't exist.

Not to mention Google Play categories are pretty bad-  things frequently don't fall into one or the other, the descriptions are vague, and they're way too broad-  they need at least 2 or 3 levels of subcategories to make them halfway usable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change API wise since the last question.

At best, you could retrieve each package name and scrape the Google Play page. However, this will fail if the app is not present on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. The solution for the above query is stated below.

Firstly, download the Jsoup library or download the jar file.

or Add this to your build.gradle(Module: app) implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

```
private class FetchCategoryTask extends AsyncTask {
private final String TAG = FetchCategoryTask.class.getSimpleName();
private PackageManager pm;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... errors) {
  String category;
  pm = getPackageManager();
  List<ApplicationInfo> packages = 
  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
  Iterator<ApplicationInfo> iterator = packages.iterator();
  //  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  // ApplicationInfo packageInfo = iterator.next();
  String query_url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
  id=com.imo.android.imoim";  //GOOGLE_URL + packageInfo.packageName;
  Log.i(TAG, query_url);
  category = getCategory(query_url);
  Log.e("CATEGORY", category);

  // store category or do something else
  //}
  return null;
 }
private String getCategory(String query_url) {
  try {
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(query_url).get();
     Elements link = doc.select("a[class=\"hrTbp R8zArc\"]");
     return link.text();
      } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("DOc", e.toString());
     }
  }
}
```

In return, you will get Application Company Name and category of the application